# Keepass and libkeepass on windows?

Tags: python, keepass

I've been using keepass and libkeepass to access the key database via Python. Although the code works on linux it does not work on Windows, I receive this error relating to the keyfile:

```
  with libkeepass.open(db_path, keyfile) as kdb:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\__init__.py", line 33, in open

  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\kdb4.py", line 380, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\kdb4.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\common.py", line 137, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\kdb4.py", line 383, in read_from
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\kdb4.py", line 72, in read_from
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\common.py", line 143, in read_from
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\libkeepass\kdb4.py", line 191, in _decrypt
IOError: Master key invalid.
```

I had quite a bit of trouble getting libkeepass installed on windows as opposed to linux. Not sure if this effecting it, the library loads fine it just doesn't seem to be able to use the keyfile.

I'm open to suggestions for a better key database that has a more robust python API if one exists, it needs to be a free to use piece of software?

TIA

Comment: "Although the code works on windows it does not work on Windows" ...wha?

Comment: lol, switch that first windows for linux. I'm trying to convey that I know the code is ok as it runs on my linux machine fine.

Comment: Which version of libkeepass are you using?

Comment: Installed via pip so it was 0.1.2